# PyUSB Barcode Scanner without Button by Honeywell

Tags: barcode-scanner, hid, pyusb, honeywell

I have a Honeywell N5600 that I'm trying to use, but I don't get it to scan anything.

The device is recognized as /dev/hidraw1, but as it does not have any button to press, I cannot trigger the scan and thus, when I try to read from it, it just waits forever.

I started creating a python program, that seems to be able to communicate with it (different return values):

```
VENDOR_LEGO = 0x0c2e
PRODUCT_EV3 = 0x0967
device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_LEGO, idProduct=PRODUCT_EV3)
device.detach_kernel_driver(0)

#"TRGMOD8." would - when scanned (which I cannot do, at this point) - activate a permanent scanning mode
device.ctrl_transfer(0x21, 0x9, wValue=0x200, wIndex=0x00, data_or_wLength='TRGMOD8.')
#8 is returned

device.ctrl_transfer(0x21, 0x9, wValue=0x200, wIndex=0x00, data_or_wLength='PAPSPC.')
#7 is returned
```

Unluckily [the link](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/CatalogDocuments/3310-QS%20Rev%20B%205-12.pdf) given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575403/pyusb-usb-barcode-scanner) post is not reachable anymore. It seems like it would have solved my problem.

How can I activate the scanning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document on Honeywell N5600 is as follows.
[N5600 OEM 2D Imager Data Sheet](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/-/media/en/files-public/data-sheets/n5600-oem-2d-imager-data-sheet-en.pdf)
[N56XX Decoded Engine User's Guide](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/en/-/media/en/files-public/technical-publications/oem-scan-engines/n5600-series/N56XX-UG%20Rev%20C%20pdf.pdf)

You need a Windows PC that can connect to the Internet, but there is a tool called EZConfig-Scanning that configures and maintains the scanner.
[EZConfig Device Management Data Sheet](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/-/media/en/files-public/data-sheets/ezconfig-device-management-data-sheet-en.pdf)

Perhaps the recognition device /dev/hidraw1 is probably because the scanner is set to USB HID Bar Code Scanner mode.

If you change the setting to USB Keyboard(PC/Mac), it is always readable and the barcode you read will be notified as keyboard input.

By changing the setting to USB Serial, reading start/stop can be controlled by SerialPort command transmission. The barcode read is notified by receiving data from SerialPort.

Comment: that was it. the device was in "USB HID" mode.. I set it to "emulate serial port" and it appeared as /dev/ttyACM0, now I can use it with pyserial
thank you. :)